# How to Create an RSS 2.0 Feed with Java

Tags: java, rss

Howto Create an RSS 2.0 Feed with JAVA.Using Strust2  development.

Answer (score 3):

I would check out the fantastic Rome library:  http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javawsxml/Rome